# Retrieving the value of mysql field from a public function of a class

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have a public function inside a class as follows

```
class View{
public function getVideoTitle($video_id)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT video_title FROM '.$this->CFG['db']['tbl']['video'].
                ' WHERE video_id='.$this->dbObj->Param('video_id');

        $stmt = $this->dbObj->Prepare($sql);
        $rs = $this->dbObj->Execute($stmt, array($video_id));
            if (!$rs)
                trigger_error($this->dbObj->ErrorNo().' '.$this->dbObj->ErrorMsg(), E_USER_ERROR);

        if($row = $rs->FetchRow())
            return $row['video_title'];             
        return;
    }
}
```

I can echo out the value of the function by doing

```
echo View::getVideoTitle(375) //where 375 is the id of the video
```

My question is how can i use the same function `getVideoTitle()` to also retrieve other fields in the database and not just title.

If i do let's say `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM....` what should i return in the function and how do use the function to echo out a certain field of this sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class View
{
    public function getField($field, $value)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT '.$field.' FROM '.$this->CFG['db']['tbl']['video'].
            ' WHERE '.$field.' = "'.$value.'");

        $stmt = $this->dbObj->Prepare($sql);
        $rs = $this->dbObj->Execute($stmt, array($video_id));
        if (!$rs)
            trigger_error($this->dbObj->ErrorNo().' '.$this->dbObj->ErrorMsg(), E_USER_ERROR);

        if($row = $rs->FetchRow())
            return $row[$field];
        return;
    }
}
```

Try this.